# What were the dimensions of the Lahitolle 95 mm cannon?

Tags: military, artillery

What were the dimensions of this gun? Specifically, I need to know the height, the width, and the length of the entire piece, not just the barrel.

Comment: About 95mm. *wakka wakka wakka*

Comment: I am voting to close this question because it is not about history.

Comment: Found some gorgeous scale drawings. I've totally updated my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found [a site with extensive information about the cannon](http://www.fortiffsere.fr/artillerie/index_fichiers/Page846.htm). It includes beautiful scale drawings. While they do not include the height and width explicitly, they do have the total length of the cannon (2.5m) which can be used to extrapolate the scale of the images in pixels / cm. Pixels are used because they will not change with your screen or zoom.

In the first image the cannon is about 700 pixels long giving 2.8 pixels / cm. In the second it is about 370 pixels long giving about 1.5 pixels / cm. These are rough measurements.

[image]

[image]

If that is not enough, the piece is located at the 
[Musee de L'artillerie](http://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g668760-d6948046-Reviews-Musee_de_L_artillerie-Draguignan_Var_Provence.html) in Draguignan, France. That link includes a phone number you can call. The curator may oblige to measure it for you.

Comment: How do you measure and extrapolate a digital image? Doesn't it depend on your screen resolution?

Comment: @user69715 Since we know the absolute length of the barrel (2.5m) you can use that to calibrate the scales. Its best to use pixels since they don't change. The 250 cm cannon is about 700 pixels long in the first image giving a ratio of 2.8 pixels / cm. In the second image it's about 370 pixels giving a ratio of about 1.5 pixels / cm.